# MySQL view built from simple views (algorithm = merge) still has performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance, view, explain

I define several basic views (Simple view with only left join operation). And then define another simple view (let's naming it as inherited_view) from those basic views. The view algorithm is merge. Simple select from the inherited_view performs terrible.

But I cannot find derived table from 'explain' output. Also I cannot understand why the performance is so bad.

Here is the explain result:
[image: view on views]

Then I try to rewrite the inherited_view from original tables directly. Then it performs much better. But the 'explain' result doesnt change too much. I am not sure why the performance improves.

Here is the explain result:

[image: view on tables]

So my question is why the performance is bad even though all views are created with algorithm = merge.
Thanks.

update view definition:

basic views are just select columns from several tables:

```
CREATE VIEW basic_View AS
SELECT column1, column2,....
FROM (((((table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.xid = table1.id 
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.yid = table1.id
  ...
where ('string1' = tablex.column1) and (value = tabley.column2);


CREATE VIEW inherited_view AS
SELECT column1, column2....
FROM basic_view1
LEFT JOIN basic_view2 on ((basic_view2.result_id = basic_view1.id and basic_view2.name = 'string1'))
LEFT JOIN basic_view2 on ((basic_view2.result_id = basic_view1.id and basic_view2.name = 'string2'))
LEFT JOIN basic_view2 on ((basic_view2.result_id = basic_view1.id and basic_view2.name = 'string3'))
```

The record number is 20 thousands.
No cache as time keeps unchanged for both case no matter how many time I run.

The query statement to test the performance is:

```
SELECT * FROM inherited_view WHERE name1 = 'str1' and name2 = 'str2';
```

The real performance data is: (I run the fast one firstly. No cache I think. The data keeps consistent.)

35 rows in set (21 sec)    for view on views

35 rows in set (0.7 sec)   for view on tables

---

Possible root cause:
The magic is in the last three LEFT JOIN or you can check the last three rows in the explain result.

```
CREATE VIEW inherited_view AS
SELECT column1, column2....
FROM basic_view1
LEFT JOIN basic_view2 on ((basic_view2.result_id = basic_view1.id and basic_view2.name = 'string1'))
LEFT JOIN basic_view2 on ((basic_view2.result_id = basic_view1.id and basic_view2.name = 'string2'))
LEFT JOIN basic_view2 on ((basic_view2.result_id = basic_view1.id and basic_view2.name = 'string3'))
```

basic_view2 is a simple view, the data looks like:

```
result_id    name     value
1            owner    Tom
1            status   Fail
2            owner    Jerry
2            status   Pass
```

From the last three rows of the explain results, you can see there are two possible_keys, first one is index of column 'result_id', and the second one is index of column 'name'.

Query of view on table, uses the first index ('result_id').

But query of view on view, uses the second index ('name').

After I drop the index of 'name', both view on view performs as well as view on table.

Any one can tell me what exactly happens? Thanks.

Comment: We need to see the relevant part of your view code, to know the structure of the relevant tables and to know how many records are stored and whether you are filtering by texts.

Comment: You didn't show us the query you used, so we have no idea how many records you're receiving back. If the query results from both views are the same, then the result gets cached. That means if your first (slow) view performs a query, then querying second view will pull from cache, ergo it appears faster. **Always** clear your cache when measuring performance. Also, you didn't provide `create view` statements, nor what your database configuration is. I doubt it's the view's fault, this is 99.9% caused by slow I/O subsystem and misconfiguration (low buffer pool etc.)

Comment: I do not know of a == operator in MySQL. You are using more tables, so I am not sure I understand your statement about the record number being 20 000, especially if I take a look at the number of rows in the second image you attached. If you do not describe your problem accurately, then we cannot help you.

Comment: This smells like an EAV schema.  Do you have `INDEX(result_id, name)`?  Or better yet, is that the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Please provide more `SHOW CREATEs`.

Comment: One thing I want to confirm is that building view upon view is not encouraged, right? Even though view algorithm can be merge.

Comment: @Lajos, forgive me. I didnt think the real number is that important. The first row of the second image shows there are 120000+ records which is after filtering.  The question here is two kind of views performances differently. The underlying tables are same that is they have the same index. Is it possible that the real execution flow is different from the explain result. Or can you see any critical difference from the two explain results. Thanks.

Comment: @Rick, we have index for result_id and name separately. Actually the index of name makes things worse. I drop that index and the view on view performs as well as view on table. Also I try to add index(result_id, name) and it doesnt help. result_id is unique but name is not. We use this EAV table as we cannot change the structure of the old table. Thanks. Do you know why view on view chooses index of name?

Comment: If `result_id` is unique, why also test against `name`?  (I am looking at the `ON`.)

Comment: @Rick, oh, you are right, result_id is not unique.

Comment: Yes. If performance is key, don't build a view of views

Comment: Mayling, I am interested to know the structure of your tables, the number of records in each and the indexes. Your views are built on the tables, so they depend on them. When you create a view, you need to make sure that the operation used by them is quick-enough. If we do not know whether your query is quick-enough, then we know nothing. If we do not know the structure and size, then we do not know whether your query is quick-enough. So, without these we are not informed-enough.